# Malformed MySQL Export

Tags: python, mysql, pandas, csv

I have a mysql table with 11 columns. I exported it to .csv with:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM my_table
INTO OUTFILE /path/.../my_table.csv
FIELDS ENCLOSED BY '"'
TERMINATED BY ';'
ESCAPED BY ""
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

Unfortunately when I try to read the file with pandas in python with:

```
df = pd.read_csv('my_table.csv', sep=';', engine='python',
                 header=None, names=my_table_headers, 
                 na_values='NULL', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
```

I get:

```
ParseError: Expected 11 fields in line 1885764, saw 12
```

Why does this happen?

**EDIT (more context):**

Here's what my mysql table looks like:

[image]

And here's the .csv file opened with TextEdit

```
"nm0000001";"Fred Astaire";"1899";"1987";"soundtrack";"actor";"miscellaneous";"tt0050419";"tt0053137";"tt0031983";"tt0072308"
"nm0000002";"Lauren Bacall";"1924";"2014";"actress";"soundtrack";NULL;"tt0071877";"tt0038355";"tt0117057";"tt0037382"
"nm0000003";"Brigitte Bardot";"1934";NULL;"actress";"soundtrack";"music_department";"tt0057345";"tt0054452";"tt0059956";"tt0049189"
"nm0000004";"John Belushi";"1949";"1982";"actor";"soundtrack";"writer";"tt0072562";"tt0080455";"tt0078723";"tt0077975"
"nm0000005";"Ingmar Bergman";"1918";"2007";"writer";"director";"actor";"tt0083922";"tt0050986";"tt0060827";"tt0050976"
"nm0000006";"Ingrid Bergman";"1915";"1982";"actress";"soundtrack";"producer";"tt0034583";"tt0036855";"tt0038109";"tt0038787"
```

**EDIT (SOLVED):**

Ok so, as suggested, I went looking for the line that gave me the error and there was a ';' in the middle of one of the fields, like:

`"some guy's ; name"`

so I changed the separator to `','` both in the MySQL export and the python code. But then another line gave me the same error so I changed the separator to `'\t'` where it was needed and opted for a `.tsv` file which is fine anyway. Everything went smooth this time. All is well that ends well. Thanks everybody.

Comment: What does line 1885764 look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your parameters don't look right especially

> escaped by ""

Please use these for csv, they work usually

```
SELECT *
INTO OUTFILE '/path/.../my_table.csv'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
ESCAPED BY '"'
FROM my_table
```

All parameters are depending on the data, when get that message , it tells you that in the one column are characters like \n or ", so you must try out the parameters.  like `ESCAPED BY '\'`

Comment: Hi, the reason for `ESCAPED BY ""` is that with `ESCAPED BY '"'` what are null values in my MySQL table look literally like this in the .csv: field_before, N", next_field. By the way I read about it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24250579/how-to-handle-null-field-when-exporting-mysql-tables-to-csv

Comment: add a row_number to the select and check line 1885764